# Checkbox only returns first value

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I´m creating a form with checkboxes. But somehow I only get the first result back..

Hope you  can help!

```
<strong>My form </strong>

<form action="historie.php" method="post">
<?php
// ophalen van bijbehorende producten
    $sql_product_opzoek = "SELECT * FROM product_bestellingen WHERE bestelnummer = $bestelnummer_opzoek";
    $sql_p_opzoek = mysqli_query($con, $sql_product_opzoek);
    $count = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_p_opzoek)) {

        $artikelnr_retour = $row['artikelnr'];
        $merk_retour = $row['merk'];
        $artikelnr_lev_retour = $row['artikelnr_lev'];
        $kleur_retour = $row['kleur'];
        $maat_retour = $row['maat'];
        $prijs_retour = $row['prijs'];


        if ($count === 0) {
            $sql_opzoek = "SELECT * FROM bestellingen WHERE bestelnummer = $bestelnummer_opzoek";
            $sql_b_opzoek = mysqli_query($con, $sql_opzoek);

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_b_opzoek)) {
                $tent = $row['tent'];
            }

            echo $tent;
        }

        echo "
            <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"retour[" . $artikelnr_retour . "]\" value=\"" . $artikelnr_retour . "\">
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"merk\" value=\"" . $merk_retour . "\">
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"art_lev\" value=\"" . $artikelnr_lev_retour . "\">

            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"kleur\" value=\"" . $kleur_retour . "\">
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"maat\" value=\"" . $maat_retour . "\">
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"prijs\" value=\"" . $prijs_retour . "\">
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"bestelnummer\" value=\"" . $bestelnummer_opzoek . "\">
        ";

        if ($count === 0) {
            echo "<input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\">";
        }

    echo "</form>";
        $count++;
}
```

This results in the next HTML

```
<strong>HTML</strong>
<form action="historie.php" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td>654655</td>
        <td>Huggo Boss</td>
        <td>xwsmcdD</td>
        <td> 13</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>€ 99,95</td>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="retour[654655]" value="654655">
            <input type="hidden" name="merk" value="Huggo Boss">
            <input type="hidden" name="art_lev" value="xwsmcdD">

            <input type="hidden" name="kleur" value=" 13">
            <input type="hidden" name="maat" value="45">
            <input type="hidden" name="prijs" value="99,95">
            <input type="hidden" name="bestelnummer" value="987654">
        </td>
        <td><input name="submit" type="submit"></td>
    </tr>
</form>
    <tr>
        <td>100254</td>
        <td>Maripe</td>
        <td>Stun</td>
        <td> 66</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>€ 295,95</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="retour[100254]" value="100254">
            <input type="hidden" name="merk" value="Maripe">
            <input type="hidden" name="art_lev" value="Stun">

            <input type="hidden" name="kleur" value=" 66">
            <input type="hidden" name="maat" value="33">
            <input type="hidden" name="prijs" value="295,95">
            <input type="hidden" name="bestelnummer" value="987654">
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

To get the results I use the next PHP

**PHP to get results**

```
 foreach ($_POST['retour'] as $value) {
     echo $value; 
 }
```

This results only in the first result: 654655

Hope you can help!

Comment: Just use  `<input type="checkbox" name="retour[]" value="654655">` and
`<input type="checkbox" name="retour[]" value="100254">`

Comment: You're missing the opening and closing `<table></table>` tags from your code, this will cause your code not to validate properly.

Comment: What's the `count($_POST['retour'])` give you?

Comment: Changed it to name="retour[]" but still just one awnser.
@Tall thank you for your answer, I stripped the code a bit to make it bit more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is close befor the second check box. Please try this code:-

```
 <strong>HTML</strong>
<form action="historie.php" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td>654655</td>
        <td>Huggo Boss</td>
        <td>xwsmcdD</td>
        <td> 13</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>€ 99,95</td>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="retour[654655]" value="654655">
            <input type="hidden" name="merk" value="Huggo Boss">
            <input type="hidden" name="art_lev" value="xwsmcdD">

            <input type="hidden" name="kleur" value=" 13">
            <input type="hidden" name="maat" value="45">
            <input type="hidden" name="prijs" value="99,95">
            <input type="hidden" name="bestelnummer" value="987654">
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>100254</td>
        <td>Maripe</td>
        <td>Stun</td>
        <td> 66</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>€ 295,95</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="retour[100254]" value="100254">
            <input type="hidden" name="merk" value="Maripe">
            <input type="hidden" name="art_lev" value="Stun">

            <input type="hidden" name="kleur" value=" 66">
            <input type="hidden" name="maat" value="33">
            <input type="hidden" name="prijs" value="295,95">
            <input type="hidden" name="bestelnummer" value="987654">
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use  `<input type="checkbox" name="retour[654655]" value="654655">`

Just use array. i.e.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="retour[]" value="654655">
<input type="checkbox" name="retour[]" value="100254">
```

This will give you `$retour[0]=654655` and `$retour[1]=100254`

Answer (score 0):

If you check both of the boxes, then both values should come through `$_POST`. If you only check one of the boxes, it only sends that value through `$_POST`.

### Example:

**One checkbox checked:**

[image: Only one checked]

**Both checkboxes checked:**

[image]

### Solution:

Try the following to make sure there is something in the `$_POST` at all times:

```
<input type="hidden" name="retour[654655]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="retour[654655]" value="1">
```

If the value of `$_POST['654655']` equals `1`, it is present. If it equals `0` it is not present. The value of a checkbox will not be submitted as long as it is not checked.With the solution presented above the value of the hidden field will be overridden when the checkbox is checked.